# Why quick sort is considered as fastest sorting algorithm?

Tags: sorting, big-o, quicksort, mergesort, heapsort

Quick sort has worst case time complexity as O(n^2) while others like heap sort and merge sort has worst case time complexity as O(n log n) ..still quick sort is considered as more fast...Why?

Comment: See [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice)

Comment: May I know the reason ..Why my question is down voted so that i ll take care of that in future?

Comment: Yes. I guess it is down-voted because (1) the question is too broad (2) you don't show any work you have done (e.g., googling the same question and reading a web-page, asking a more specific question after reading more about it, or writing a piece of code and analyzing different sorting algorithms on different scenarios, then asking a question about your code, etc.) Please also read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok ...I ll take care of this in future...and I am new to this field so I didn't know much about it...although I have already googled it ...but I was unable to understand those...I was unable to find a clear and easy exaplaination for this..so I posted it here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a side note, if sorting an array of integers, then counting / radix sort is fastest.

In general, merge sort does more moves but fewer compares than quick sort. The typical implementation of merge sort uses a temp array of the same size as the original array, or 1/2 the size (sort 2nd half into second half, sort first half into temp array, merge temp array + 2nd half into original array), so it needs more space than quick sort which optimally only needs log2(n) levels of nesting, and to avoid worst case nesting, a nesting check may be used and quick sort changed to heap sort, (this is called introsort).

If the compare overhead is greater than the move overhead, then merge sort is faster. A common example where compares take longer than moves would be sorting an array of pointers to strings. Only the (4 or 8 byte) pointers are moved, while the strings may be significantly larger (and similar for a large number of strings).

If there is significant pre-ordering of the data to be sorted, then timsort (fixed sized runs) or a "natural" merge sort (variable sized runs) will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that quicksort has worst case time complexity of *O(n^2)*, as long as the quicksort implementation properly randomizes the input, its  average case (expected) running time is *O(n log n)*.

Additionally, the constant factors hidden by the asymptotic notation that do matter in practice are pretty small as compared to other popular choices such as merge sort.  Thus, in expectation, quicksort will outperform other *O(n log n)* comparison sorts despite the less savory worst case bounds

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly like that. Quicksort is the best in most cases, however it's pesimistic time complexity can be O(n^2), it doesn't mean it always is. The issue lies in choosing the right point of pivot, if you choose it correctly you have time complexity O(n log n). 
In addition, quicksort is one of the cheapest/easiest in implementation.